# force excel cells to follow position of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, exception

i have a two tabs excel, in the first one the user input some data, then in the second tab the first five column are populated with the info from the first tab, the position of these data is relative to the position of the data in the first tab
so for example, if a user populate the first and tenth row in the first tab, then only the first and tenth row of the second tabs are populated.
thing is after the fifth column in the spreadsheet the user can put some more info regarding the data (like comments or other) and those cells are hardcoded by the user, so is someone happen to do a sorting action in the first tab the five columns in the second tab would also change position but not the other column after that, leaving behind the eventual data.
is there a way to force the cells after the fifth column to just "follow" the position of the data in the first five?

Comment: Excel will leave rows intact when sorting. But by specifying a particular range you can force Excel to leave some cells in their original position. This is determined by the sort. On the other sheet the sequence is determined by the method of referencing. If some  cells follow the sort and others don't you must be using different methods. Apply the same method to all cells, choosing the one that behaves as you prefer.

Comment: If the comments are added to the second sheet there is no easy way to force them to follow the sort on the first sheet. Any method you might design would (a) involve VBA and (b) require a system by which comments are linked to particular entries so that they can be returned to their "owners" when torn apart.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to avoid using VBA you can achieve this if you are ok to add some technical columns.

Sheet1:

1. Change your source in sheet1 to table format (this will make sure formulas are copied down when user add data;
2. add a technical column (can be hidden, copy paste link from the user input column in sheet 2) e.g. Sheet1!B:B;

Sheet2:

3. Add 2 columns:
   => user input (unsorted) e.g. col.D, (This is the column that user can edit)
   => user input sorted (users should not edit this column)
4. Add a tech column (can be hidden) with :  MATCH(D3;Sheet1!B:B;0)
5. Add in the "user input sorted": INDEX(D:D;MATCH(ROW();G:G;0);1)

When the sheet 1 is sorted, the tech column will also be sorted, we then use this info to find back the original comment, define it's new row nr and show it in the sorted col. on sheet 2. This will not work if 2 comments can be exactly the same!

Note!
for the formulas to work, you'll need to change my semicomma's to a comma if you are on a US Excel  (I'm on EU).

best of luck,

ceci